# preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

i got this error when i'm trying to send multiple email, and i also want to pass a data to mail view.

here is my controller:

```
$get_no_inven = Permohonan::find($id_per)->no_inventaris;
    $get_users = DB::table('users')->where('hak_akses','=','deputi')->get(['email']);
    
    $recipients = [ $get_users ];

    $subject = 'Testing email no 2';
    $meta = 'meta';

    foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
        // here you declare variables accesable in view file
        $dataToPassToEmailView = [];
        // **key** of this table is variable **name in view**
        $dataToPassToEmailView['no_inventaris'] = $get_no_inven;

        Mail::send('mailkedua', $dataToPassToEmailView, function($message) use ($subject, $recipient, $meta) {
            $message->to($recipient, 'Deputi Manager')->subject($subject);
            $message->from('app.staging@nutrifood.co.id','Kalibrasi Online');
        });
    }
```

and here is my mail view:

```
<p>Dear Deputi Manager,</p>

<p>Berikut kami informasikan terdapat hasil kalibrasi terbaru alat dengan nomor inventaris {{$no_inventaris}}
Mohon bantuannya untuk melakukan approval, silahkan akses "Link CALON" <a href="http://baf-staging-x2:3030/lihat_permohonan_deputi/">http://baf-staging-x2:3030/lihat_permohonan_deputi/</a></p>


<p>Terima kasih,</p>
<p>CALON</p>
```

i don't understand where i'm doing wrong, thankyou!

Comment: The code you have shown so far does not even contain `preg_match` anywhere. PHP error messages usually contain file name and line number, for a reason …

Comment: is there a reason you are wrapping the result set returned from the query in an array?   remove that array wrapping

Comment: The error message tells you whats wrong. Also if you want help show us the part where the error actually happens. Where do you find the error? The error message tells you also the file and the line (which you didnt provide).

Comment: i don't know why i got this error because i'm not type preg_match anywhere

Comment: and the error message is only "ErrorException in MailboxHeader.php line 344:
preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given"

Comment: That is because  $recipient is an object and you pass it to $message->to($recipient, 'Deputi Manager'), it should be a email address. lagbox 's answer would fix that ithink.

Comment: what version of Laravel 5 btw?

Comment: its laravel 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the result of your query in an array. Also if you only want the `email` field from these records you could use `pluck` to get a list of them:

```
$recipients = DB::table('users')->where('hak_akses','=','deputi')->pluck('email');

foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    ...
}
```

This would make `$recipient` a string for the email address.

Comment: thumbs up for your last adit, this explains whats wrong

Comment: thank you so much for helping me, god bless you!